# AppIntent information to show custom “Requires” label & description

Tags: ios, swift, sirishortcuts, appintents

Is there a way to show a custom “Requires” label in the AppIntent/Shortcut action information view (when pressing the i-button)?

I’ve seen this label in actions like the “Add New Reminder” of the Reminders app or “Log Workout” of the Health app.

I fear that this label is automatically shown for actions that require access to privacy related data (like health, location, etc.). Though, maybe there is a way to show this with a custom label and description? For context I’d like to inform the user there that they require an active subscription to use the Shortcut.

[image]
[image]